# Can I add two .htaccess in one website one for a folder and other for website?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanted to add two htaccess file in one website one for website and other for a folder .
Can you guys help with this.

Comment: Help with __what exactly__?

Comment: I want to two .htaccess file in my website. One id for whole website and other one is for a folder.

Comment: Just go to [**Apache docs**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) and read it by yourself

Comment: `I want` is not a problem description, read [ask] or [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add `.htaccess` file for specific folder (just add it into folder).

Comment: I have done this but it's not working it always pick htaccess that I have put in to the root